# GCP App Engine - How to delete custom domain from deleted project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I want to add a custom subdomain to my gcp app engine. Unfortunately I already mapped this subdomain to another app engine project that is deleted. As long as the subdomain is mapped to the deleted project I cannot add it to the new project.

What i have done so far:

- In my new project I opened the settings of the app engine.
- Under new custom domain I wanted to add a custom domain.
- There I chose my already verified subdomain.
- When i wanted to assign the subdomain under I get the message: 'sub.domain.com is already assigned to a project'.
- I also tried to delete the domain mapping with *gcloud app domain-mappings delete 'sub.domain.com'* in the shell but that doesn't work because: *Domain 'sub.domain.com' is not mapped to application 'my-new-project'* and the old project is already deleted.

Is there any possible solution to delete this domain mapping and 'free' the subdomain?

Comment: Subdomains are mapped to resources via DNS resource records (A, CNAME, etc). To change the DNS resource record, edit the record and point it to your new resource. Edit your question with details on what you have tried, error messages, and the problem description so that we can better understand your issue.

Comment: When you delete a project the resources are archived for 30 days. Undelete the project and remove the mapping. If you have a billing/payments problem, then you have a different problem. Edit your question with more context on this issue.

Comment: I have updated my question. I can't point my subdomain DNS records to the new resource as I cannot map the subdomain to my new project first in the gcp. But I have now deleted the existing DNS records that pointed to the old project.

Comment: Deleting a project is not related to DNS server resource records. Do you mean that Google Cloud does not allow you to delete the custom mapping? Follow the steps in my previous comment and undelete the project, remove the mapping and continue as normal.

Comment: I could restore the project. Now the problem is, that the app engine of that project is not restored. It seems that the project is restored as a kind of 'empty' project. Therefore I cannot remove the mapping.

Comment: Do/did you have a billing issue? If not, then you will need to open a support ticket.

Comment: There are no billing issues as far as I can oversee it. At least it worked in the past. 
As I don't have paid support I will just create a new domain and use that. Not the cleanest solution but at least I can keep on working.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found out a solution for your issue. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution for my issue. I just created a new domain but the existing domain is still mapped and cannot be deleted.

Comment: As @John Hanley mentioned i think you have to create a [Support Case with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) as it requires more in-depth analysis to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gcloud` command line:

```
gcloud config set project **deleted-project-id**
```

(find it through email alert  while delete from google console - check your mailbox)

```
gcloud app domain-mappings delete example.com

gcloud app domain-mappings delete www.example.com
```

Further Help:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/domain-mappings/delete